# How to flatten extra dimensions in lists down into a single dimension for Python?

Tags: python, list, square-bracket

Question1. Do you always have to convert a list to string to remove square brackets?

Main Question. I want to remove extra square brackets of a list nested in a list. The [] index of the nested list will change when the words change

Example

Words = ['Red Shirt', ['Minions', 'Expendables', 'Cannon Fodder']]

Comment: No. there is no reason to convert to string, you can manipulate lists as you please. [ask]

Comment: You have a list with one two elements.  "Red Shirt" and a list of strings.  Are you asking how to flatten that nested list into one single list?

Comment: You're not removing brackets. The data structure has no brackets. The ***string representation*** of the data structure has brackets to tell you what is a list object. What you want to do is take a list with one or more lists inside it, and move the inner lists' contents to the outer list. As per the previous comment, that's flattening the lists. But, a better approach would be to generate the list "correctly" in the first place. So, how did you generate this list?

Comment: so that would be the term "flatten", thanks @ewokx

Comment: @MatBailie  I created an empty list, and appended the word redshirt and then the list of 3 words.
How would you suggest to generate a list correctly?

Comment: Edit your question to show the code that generated the list. You must have been processing some other data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking to flatten a list -- or the process of removing the "extra dimensions" of a list of lists down into a single dimension.

There's a lengthy discussion on in the thread linked here, but I have linked to *my* preferred solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/9453914

Your solution will be a little different as you'll first need to add a few more brackets to make your life a little easier, however, this should work for the example given above

```py
Words = ['Red Shirt', ['Minions', 'Expendables', 'Cannon Fodder']]
words = [[entry] if type(entry) == str else entry for entry in Words ]
flattened = [word for l in words for word in l]
flattened
>>> ['Red Shirt', 'Minions', 'Expendables', 'Cannon Fodder']
```

Where we need to nest `'Red Shirt'` in its own list first so flattening the entry doesn't start splitting the string into individual characters.